# pandas.concat forgets column names

Tags: pandas, merge, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new `DataFrame` from columns of two existing frames but after the `concat()`, the column names are lost and I can't assign new ones:

```
import pandas
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'value': [1.1, 2.1], 'foo': ['a', 'b']}, index=[dt(2015, 11, 1), dt(2015, 11, 2)])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'value': [1.2, 2.2]}, index=[dt(2015, 11, 3), dt(2015, 11, 4)])

# Keeps 'foo'
df = pandas.concat([df1, df2])
print df
print

# Without foo but column names are also lost
# plus there is an additional odd line "Name: value, dtype: float64"
df = pandas.concat([df1['value'], df2['value']])
print df
print

# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
print repr(df.columns)
# no effect (probably because this isn't a supported attribute)
df.columns = ['value']
print df

# Fails: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "columns"
df.rename(columns={'': 'value'}, inplace=True)
print df
```

Output that I get:

```
2015-11-01    1.1
2015-11-02    2.1
2015-11-03    1.2
2015-11-04    2.2
```

Output that I want:

```
            value
2015-11-01    1.1
2015-11-02    2.1
2015-11-03    1.2
2015-11-04    2.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because:

```
df = pandas.concat([df1['value'], df2['value']])
```

is concatenating 2 `Series` objects rather than dfs,

if you did this:

```
In [201]:
df = pd.concat([df1[['value']], df2[['value']]])
df

Out[201]:
            value
2015-11-01    1.1
2015-11-02    2.1
2015-11-03    1.2
2015-11-04    2.2
```

then you get a df with a 'value' column

The double `[[]]` is forcing a df to be returned as it interprets the passed in param as a list of cols (with only 1 entry) rather than a column label which will return a `Series` which is by design

you can see the difference here:

```
In [202]:
print(type(df1['value']))
print(type(df1[['value']]))

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

the rest of your code fails because the object is of type `Series` and it makes no sense for a `Series` to have a `columns` attribute or to allow renaming of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found it best to do this.

```
new_df = pd.concat([my_df1, my_df2.rename('Name')], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Assume that readers of your answer are not 100% familiar with the technology. Please explain in more detail why you do this, why it's "best" and what important parts mean (for example, how does the rename work in your case).